# How to change background color of list item image bullet?

Tags: html, css, list, background

I have a list with this CSS:

```
li
{
    list-style-image: url('../img/arrow.gif');
}
li:hover
{
    background-color:#E2E1D6;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Semantic Web</li>
    <li> Web 2.0</li>
</ul>
```

but on hover, background color of list bullet section (including transparent arrow image) not changed:

[image]

I want like this:

[image]

**[JSFilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqf1stam/)**

How can I change background color of bullet section of list item?

Comment: This should work. Please also show your HTML.

Comment: Are you talking about the background of the green arrow or the "sematic web"?

Comment: @Cyzanfar Yes. I want all section of `li` (also its bullet) color changed.

Comment: Include your html please

Comment: @Cyzanfar I added HTML +JSFiddle.

Comment: @dirkk  I added HTML +JSFiddle.

Comment: is the image is transparent?

Comment: @RonakJain Yes it is!

Comment: just add list-style-position: inside to li .. try it the in fiddle, it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use :

```
li{
list-style-image:url();
list-style-position: inside;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/pqf1stam/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can add the bullet as a background image.

```
li
{
    background: url(http://x.majidr.ir/arrow.gif) no-repeat;
    padding-left:20px;
    list-style:none;
}
li:hover
{
    background-color:#E2E1D6;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pqf1stam/1/

Comment: on right to left direction, padding will not work well.

Comment: You could use background-position instead of padding. However, @Ronak Jain's solution is the best :)

Answer (score 1):

i would do it via background image

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/david321312312231/pqf1stam/3/

```
li
{
    background: url('http://x.majidr.ir/arrow.gif') left center no-repeat;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
li:hover
{
    background-color:#E2E1D6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

li
{
  background:url('../img/arrow.gif') top left no-repeat;
  padding-left:24px;
}

li:hover
{
  background-color:#E2E1D6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/HequH/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="test.html">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="test2.html">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="test3.html">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { 
    list-style-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b9c1eafa90f9b895aff24750f7be1cbc?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG');
}

ul li:hover { 
    list-style-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/459f72f7a692a760ddfd30340aac2901?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
}

li:hover a { color: #f00; }
```

Comment: that would mean that he has another image of the arrow with a grey background

Answer (score 0):

use `list-style-position: inside;`

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code, you don't need to call images form outside of your image directory. Here you could use item image bullet as background image. Please see the code.

HTML:

```
  <ul>
      <li><a href="">Semantic Web</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Semantic Web</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Semantic Web</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Semantic Web</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Semantic Web</a></li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none
   }
ul li {
    background-image: url("images/arrow1.gif");
    background-position: 0 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
    }
ul li:hover {
    background-color:#E2E1D6
    }
ul li a {
    color:#fff;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;
    }
ul li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    }
```

Demo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211935016/list_bullet/index.html